# Wrong groupby by DATE_FORMAT in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

There is a following query model:

```
return \DB::table('clients')->select(DB::raw("
            DATE_FORMAT(result_test.created_at, '%M %e %Y') AS day,
            COUNT(result_test.id) AS passed"))
            ->leftJoin('result_test', 'result_test.client_id', '=', 'clients.id')
            ->where('clients.doctor_id', $user_id)
            ->whereBetween('result_test.created_at', array($startDate, $endDate))
            ->orderBy('result_test.created_at')
            ->groupBy('day')
            ->get();
```

Please, note on the piece:

```
DB::raw("
                DATE_FORMAT(result_test.created_at, '%M %e %Y') AS day,
                COUNT(result_test.id) AS passed")
```

After that I tried to group rows by `AS day`:

```
->groupBy('day')
```

And I have got this error message:

```
42000/1055 - db.result_test.created_at' isn't in GROUP BY
```

What is wrong with query?

When I have removed this: `->orderBy('result_test.created_at')`  it becomes to work. Why?

Comment: Follow the duplicate link.  I think `groupBy(DB::raw('day'))` should work for you.

Comment: I dont have the same column with name `day` in two joined table. I am sure about that

Comment: I tried: `->groupBy(DB::raw('day'))` it does not work for me - the same error

Comment: I don't know why, but it requires to use two fields in group by: `->groupBy(DB::raw('day, result_test.created_at'))`

Comment: That makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this because `'result_test.created_at'` is not in a select Group.

```
return \DB::table('clients')->select('result_test.created_at',DB::raw("
            DATE_FORMAT(result_test.created_at, '%M %e %Y') AS day,
            COUNT(result_test.id) AS passed"))
            ->leftJoin('result_test', 'result_test.client_id', '=', 'clients.id')
            ->where('clients.doctor_id', $user_id)
            ->whereBetween('result_test.created_at', array($startDate, $endDate))
            ->orderBy('result_test.created_at')
            ->groupBy('day')
            ->get();
```

Hope this helps.